# How is the interchange of the radial space component and time on the black hole horizon to be interpreted physically?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

On the event horizon of a black hole (or just behind it), the radial component of the metric is interchanged with its time component. How can this be interpreted? Extra question: what happens to these components when you look exactly on the horizon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a Schwarzschild BH, there is a $coordinate~singularity$ in Schwarzschild coordinates $t,~r,~\theta,~\phi$ at the event horizon. This is similar to asking what happens at longitude 0 on Earth - the longitude coordinate has a discontinuity there. If you perform a coordinate transformation to something like [Kruskal-Szerkes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) coordinates which can describe spacetime inside an event horizon, you can see that there isn't actually a singularity at the event horizon.

Comment: This only addresses the "extra question" by the OP and completely ignores the question of the interchange of the timelike to spacelike nature of the $t$ coordinate and vice-versa for the $r$ coordinate.

Answer (score 5):

This interchange has no physical meaning; it is simply an oddity of the coordinate system being used. Spacetime at the black hole horizon is “locally flat” just as it is everywhere else, except at the singularity. This means that, by choosing appropriate “normal” coordinates in the vicinity of any point on the horizon, the metric can be made to look Minkowskian to first order in those coordinates.

If you are freely falling through the horizon and do experiments in a sufficiently small region as you pass through, you will therefore get similar results to those you’d get in the freely-falling International Space Station. There might be larger tidal effects around the black hole (or not, depending on the mass), but those can be made *arbitrarily small* by confining your experiment to a smaller volume. These effects arise from the second-order non-Minkowskian corrections to the metric.

Comment: The interchange does have some quasi-physical significance tho, right? In particular, it predicts that the radial direction is the timelike direction beyond the horizon whereas it is a spacelike direction outside the horizon. Sure "radial" is coordinate dependent and thus, ultimately, meaningless. But while Schwarzschild coordinates are as such bad coordinates, they are also good coordinates in that they reflect a physically clear picture of a blackhole in a way that the good coordinates like Kruskal don't. [..]

Comment: [...] For example, if someone were to hand down to us the Kruskal metric without us knowing anything about the Schwarzschild metric, it would be damn hard to imagine what a black hole would look like. I think what I am trying to convey is that the interchange of the timelike-spacelike nature in the Schwarzschild coordinates corresponds to the physically important fact that you can't get out of a blackhole, i.e., there is a $r=r_S$ hypersurface beyond which going towards smaller $r$ is inevitable because it simply means moving forward in time.

Comment: That arbitrarily small volume needs to be quite small near a stellar mass BH. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification a 1 m rod of mass 1 kg with tensile strength 10000 N falling vertically toward a 10 solar mass BH (Schwarzschild radius ~30 km) breaks from the tidal force at ~320 km.

Comment: It is [well-known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4184.pdf) that there are coordinate systems in which *every component* of the Riemann tensor is *finite* at the horizon. The fact that a few components diverge at the horizon in Schwarzschild coordinates is merely an unphysical pathology of those particular coordinates. Manifolds are locally flat except at singularities, *by definition*. There is *nothing* singular about the horizon of a Schwarzschild hole. Its horizon-ness arises from the global properties of the spacetime, not the local ones at the horizon.

Comment: In a mainstream understanding of classical GR, there are local inertial frames not just outside the hole but also at the horizon and even inside, except at the true singularity.

Comment: The local flatness of a LIF means that tidal (i.e., curvature) effects can be made arbitrarily small by restricting one’s attention to a sufficiently small region.

Comment: @safesphere That paper doesn't claim that the spacetime can be extended analytically at $r=0$ in the usual sense. It talks about a decrease in the spacetime dimension, etc. I think it's probably just wrong, but if it's right then it's similar to conformal cyclic cosmology, where you deal with the singularity by changing the rules. Note that the paper correctly says "there are other coordinates […] which remove the singularity $r=2m$ […] This shows that the event horizon singularity is due to the coordinates […] changing the coordinates cannot be used to remove the singularity $r=0$".

Comment: @safesphere The integrated proper time along any causal worldline is still finite (and at most a few microseconds per solar mass) notwithstanding that the coordinate time goes off to infinity.

Comment: @safesphere The singularity is never part of the manifold. When people say a manifold "has" a singularity, they really mean it's [geodesically incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_manifold). Interesting discussion in [Geroch 1968](http://www.god-does-not-play-dice.net/Geroch_1968.pdf).